# jQuery Find option by text and move it to top of select

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find an option in a select by it's text and move that option to the top of the select but I can't seem to get it, using version 1.9.1.

```
// move 'untagged' option to top of select
jQuery('#logical_interface_vlan_id option:[text="Untagged"]').prependTo(jQuery('#logical_interface_vlan_id'));
```

`logical_interface_vlan_id` is the id of the select and `Untagged` is the option text I am looking for.

The above gives me an unrecognized expression syntax error.

I also tried this, no errors but it didn't do anything either:

```
jQuery('#logical_interface_vlan_id').find('option[text="Untagged"]').prependTo(jQuery('#logical_interface_vlan_id'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop through the options and then remove and prepend that way

```
jQuery('#logical_interface_vlan_id option').each(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).text() === 'Untagged') {
            var option = jQuery(this);
            jQuery(this).remove();
            jQuery('#logical_interface_vlan_id').prepend(option);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the id of your select is - `#osmBodyContent_ddlPosition`

Get the selected option first and store it in a variable -

```
var selectedOpt = $("#osmBodyContent_ddlPosition option:selected");
```

Then remove the selected option -

```
$(selectedOpt ).remove();
```

Now prepend it to the top -

```
$("#osmBodyContent_ddlPosition").prepend(selectedOpt)
```

Comment: Why not using the `variable` you've created on the second command?

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm looking for, the option I want has specific text and isn't the selected option.